# How can I configure Pericom Tandem Emulator(TN6530) with QTP

Tags: qtp, hp-uft, terminal-emulator, tandem

I know how to connect Hummingbird with QTP but dont know how to configure Pericom Tandem Emulator(TN6530) .
I dont even know if it supports hillapi or not. 
Please provide detailed answer.

Comment: I like the " Please provide detailed answer" part best

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest you take a look at the last time you posted this query as it was answered quite comprehensively?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36911810/can-we-automate-pericom-teamtalk-terminal-emulator-i-e-mainframe-application-us

Comment: I have tried .., QTP 10 with teemtalk tt320iw.. when I click on finish.qtp crashes..system reboots..